# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php

```
function removeMovie($link, $title){
        $sth = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM film WHERE title=:title");
        $sth->bindValue (':title ', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        echo 'Removing succeed, <a href="wmdb.php"> Ga back</a>';


    var_dump ($sth->errorInfo());
    }
```

I receive the following error message:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid > parameter number: parameter was not defined in D:\Libraries\Documents\ICT\Webprogrammeren\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\Huiswerk\Week 5\functions.php on line 39

```
$link
```

is the database connection i'm making

I've searched google for a long time now and I can't find the right answer. A  lot of have a typo but I can't seem to find the typo. So it must be something else:

I have a database with two tables which are connected with one and each other through genre_id. Maybe this has something to do when I try to delete it?

Kind regards,
Danny

Comment: You have a space after `:title` in your bindValue() call

Comment: Unbelievable, I didn't know that would affect it at all. . Thanks dear sir!